# Would a poison-immune creature be affected by Myconid spores?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, poison, immunities

One of my players has a Yuan-ti Pureblood character. We've read somewhere that poison immunity extends to many substances and we've gone with this interpretation, for instance we're considering this character to be unable to get drunk.

So I've been wondering, would such a character be affected by Myconid spores? Of course some of the effects mention that the target is poisoned, and those would be out of the question.

But what about more 'innocuous' stuff like the Rapport Spores? The monster manual does state that undead, constructs and elementals are not affected by them. These are all creatures who are traditionally immune to poison, yet they could have stated that the spores don't work on all poison-immune creatures, and they didn't.

So would Rapport Spores and the like work on our Yuan-ti?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## RAW, the spores work.

*Volo's Guide* states that the Yuan-ti are "Immune to poison damage and the poisoned condition." (120).

This ability says nothing about other toxins (alcohol, rapport sports, etc). The immunity only extends, specifically, to poison damage and the poisoned condition.

For example, the myconid's [Pacifying Spores](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/3158-myconid) are neither poison nor poison damage. The Yuan-ti could still be stunned by that ability.

Your extended reading is a table ruling.

If you decide to maintain your broader ruling (the player has presumably benefited from it so far in some ways so a negative here seems fair), keep in mind there may be similar conflicts in the future. Additionally, prepare for further philosophical arguments about whether an effect is caused by a poison or not.

Comment: To be fair, it wasn't a benefit, just a bit of colour. Alcohol is a poison, after all (even though the official rules do not touch it, and I can see why). I have already introduced one negative side-effect of that ruling, in that the character cannot benefit from a calming concoction used to stave off nightmares in my Underdark (my Underdark is a bit peculiar, long story short, it's a separate plane and a Lovecraftian one at that).
But I agree it would be sensible to go a bit more RAW when monsters are concerned.

Comment: Sounds like you all have adopted this feature as an interesting bit of roleplaying to use as flavor. I like your approach, keeping it to small out-of-combat matters. As long as you have player buy-in for these rulings, that's what counts!

Comment: Note that the Myconid you're linking to is a homebrew playable race. Presumably OP's referring to the myconid monsters that appear in the MM instead.

Comment: Thanks. I referenced the wording in this link against the MM, and it is exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: @V2Blast what would be the best way to catalog that caveat? Is it sufficient to note it in the comments, or should a statement be edited into the answer text? In this case, the reference is only an example, so I don't find it a critical correction.

Comment: @JohnMickey: Just edit the answer to be the most up-to-date version of itself, citing the official (monster) version instead. There's no need to retain inaccurate information in the answer. (Note that unlike myconids' other spore-based abilities, the [Myconid Sovereign](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/myconid-sovereign)'s Hallucination Spores action does cause the poisoned condition.)

Comment: Yes, the Hallucination Spores were the ones that sparked the question because of their explicit mention of the Poisoned condition, which then prompted me to think that the omission of such wording in the other abilities might have been deliberate, and not just a case of writing in "too plain English".